# Adding Onto NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an NSString that I would like to add extra characters to.  In my mind I thought it would be something simple like this:

```
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", finalVolume] + @" Cubic Feet";
```

But that did not work.  Does anyone know what I might be missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` is immutable, so you cannot just add to it. Instead, you either compose your string like this:

```
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f Cubic Feet", finalVolume];
```

or

```
NSString *unit = @"Cubic Feet";
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %@", finalVolume, unit];
```

or create a mutable one:

```
NSMutableString *answerString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%f ", finalVolume];
[answerString appendString:@"Cubic Feet"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can append anything you like...

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can do the following:

```
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f Cubic Feet", finalVolume];
```

or if the part being appended needs to be variable you can do the following:

```
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %@", finalVolume, myVariable];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", finalVolume] stringByAppendingString:@" Cubic Feet"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %@", finalVolume,@"Cubic Feet"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str appendString:@"s1"];
[str appendString:@"s2"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSString stringwithformat:@"%f %@", final value, @"cubic feet"];
```